Will a CAN bus signal open up a relay?
My car has CAN bus.
And I want to connect the one end of a cable into the high beam light signal and the other end into pin 86 on a relay. Will the CAN bus signal that goes through this cable open up the relay when I switch on the high beam headlight?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No. The CAN-bus is a communication bus with very specific voltages/impedances that are intended for accurate communication and to avoid signal reflections, and it carries data encoded in complex signal patterns, not just a simple electrical pulse:

Image source: Digikey blog
The exact meaning of the message is encoded in the exact pattern of high/low periods, and a simple relay would not be able to distinguish the CAN bus signal you care about (the high-beam headlight) from other messages on the bus.
It's quite possible that the high-beam headlight module might provide a suitable output, but this is still fragile:

It might detect specific headlight current as part of dead-bulb detection
It may not be able to withstand inductive loads like relay coils
It may not output 12 V or have the correct output impedance, especially if it's intended to drive certain LEDs.

In principle, you could install and configure a CAN bus module that detects the necessary message and is intended to drive a relay, but this would require some more investigation regarding where you can tap into the CAN bus without messing up termination and bus load.

This is strange because the previous owner of the car had the setup I outline in my question above, but he removed the auxilary headlights that this relay controlled. The speedometer display shows a light warning just for saying that.

@DaffyDuck The CAN bus cannot directly connect to a relay. However, the CAN bus can connect to a device which can communicate messages on the CAN bus and then control a relay based on those messages.

I think my car has some magic setup

@DaffyDuck If you have an objective schematic diagram of that setup, we can certainly take a look at it and dispel whatever thing seems to be magical. Chances are you're thinking of a CAN-connected line that isn't itself a CAN bus, or there's some intermediary/converter, but without details we can't really guess at it.
